# Change default C++ standard in g++

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, g++

In order to compile a program in C++11 standard we need to do :

```
 g++ -std=c++11 myProgram.cpp -o myProgramExec
```

But is it possible that i can set the default standard of g++ as C++11, so that i don't have to mention this option again and again Although i can also add an alias for this in my .bashrc :

```
alias g++='g++ -std=c++11';
```

But i wonder if there is any better way than this.Is there any config file of g++ which can be edited in order to achieve this? Or is there some easier way to do this?

Comment: From `g++6.0` on, the default standard is `-std=c++14`.

Answer (score 10):

After a bit of research (which you've probably already done yourself), I haven't found a way to change the default behavior of `g++` other than rebuilding a custom version or aliasing it.

---

**Why this is probably a good thing**:

It is important that each version of `g++` has a single, well-defined default behavior. Consider this: if you change the default behavior of `g++` and try to compile a C++ project whose author could not be aware of your configuration, the project may fail to compile or compile with subtle errors / unexpected behaviors.

In your own project, you can easily add all the relevant flags and options to your `Makefile` or `CMakeLists.txt` so that you don't need to type them again. This will also ensure that other people compiling your project will receive the correct options regardless of their configuration.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @jbapple Edited with my best answer to the question (which is a bit disappointing).

Answer (score 2):

I realise this post is old but i want to reply as it kept showing up whilst i was trying to do this.

It is possible to change the default standard by modifying the g++ spec file.

Find a list of spec file locations by running

```bash
strace g++ 2>&1 | grep specs
```

This will give you the list of file paths gcc will look in.
Pick one and create a file named `spec` in that location

To check its working run

```bash
g++ -v
```

The first line of the result will say
`Reading specs from <path to specs file>`

Next run

```bash
g++ -dumpspecs > spec
```

This will pit the default spec file into your custom one

The final step is to open the specs file and find the line `*cc1plus:`
Go to the line below and add `%{!std*:-std=<desired default standard>}`

Save the file and that should work

Now when you compile without specifying a standard, the one you put in the spec file will be the ine that is used

More on spec files: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html