# how to configure -std=c++11 as default compiler?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

Hi i am working on C++11 related feature , i need to include header file such as

```
 #include <zmqpp/zmqpp.hpp>
```

in my source code and i wrote some simple g++ script to compile it such as

```
g++ client.c  -o client
```

i just realized i need to run it with additional argument

```
g++ -std=gnu++11  client.c .......
```

in order for me compile successfully.

I am curious what is the default compiler for g++? is it possible for me set
-std=gnu++11  as my default c++ compiler?

Let me know if this duplicated, i was googling around but i don't see  any information related to my scenario. Thanks

Comment: are you compiling it via command line? IDE?

Comment: hi i am compiling via command line

Comment: You can use make or cmake to simplify the process, so you don't have to type everything each time.

Comment: As an aside, if the default for your compiler isn't at least `c++11` then it's rather old.  Probably worth updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648978/change-default-c-standard-in-g), the only way to change the standard version is to rebuild a custom version of g++. If you are using Linux, I recommend having a custom alias in .bashrc, like so:

```
alias g++11='g++ -std=c++11';
```

CMake is another common method to do this, simply add this directive to make the default version C++11 :

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

Keep in mind CMake is typically used for projects, so it may not be applicable to your use case.