# Can you update the g++ command to compile with c++11 by default?

Tags: c++, c++11, terminal, compilation, g++

I'm new to c++ programming, and I'm also using emacs to write code in instead of using an IDE because my friend said getting comfortable with terminal and emacs will benefit me later on.

That said, I have to constantly compile my programs in the terminal using "g++ <file_name_here>"
It's been great until today, when trying to learn vectors.

Here is the problem I ran into when I tried to compile like this:
~/Documents/cpp/cpp_practice master ?5 > g++ vector_prac_1.cpp

```
vector_prac_1.cpp:16:27: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
  vector <int> test_scores {100, 98, 89, 85, 93}; // you can also initialize elements just like array
                          ^
                          ;
```

Then after looking around I decided to try to compile with "g++ -std=c++11 vector_prac_1.cpp"
And it worked with no problems.

So should I just compile everything with "g++ -std=c++11 <file_name_here>" from now on?  Or is there a way to change something so I'm always compiling that way by default?

Comment: Current versions of gcc compile C++11 by default. Update your compiler.

Comment: And GCC 11 will be C++17 by default

Comment: Type `g++ --version`.  What does it say for a version number?  As others have suggested, newer versions typically default to `--std=c++11` or higher. I'm curious if that's the case for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default C++ standard in g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648978/change-default-c-standard-in-g)

Comment: There are several standards defined on a compiler, you will need to figure out if you need the functionality from C++11, C++17 or C++20, there is no golden rule. C++11 is a very used standard and I would suggest that you keep using it as it is by far the most used version of the standard, but take a look on the differences to C++17 to see what is new on the language. I do not think there is a way to set C++11 as default for g++, however you can create an alias on your shell to add the flag if you think that is necessary. The common practice is to define it in a Makefile or under CMake.

Comment: Are you compiling the files specifically, or are you using a makefile? You can always set flags in the makefile. `CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11`

Comment: This might also do it: https://www.fosslinux.com/39386/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-gcc-and-g-on-ubuntu-20-04.htm#:~:text=%20Creating%20a%20list%20of%20GCC%20and%20G%2B%2B,same%20and%20choose%20our%20default%20G...%20More%20