# change the standard language in g++

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw

I want to change the standard language in c++ permanently so I no longer need to type `g++ -std=c++17 <filename>` repeatedly to change the language version which was previously c++14, and that also affects vscode which I use because the compiler can't track the language rules of version c++17, it affects the editor and displays warnings and errors. I'm using Windows 10 OS, using g++ version 8.1.0, with standard language c++14, and text editor vs code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable C++17 support in VSCode C++ Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397233/how-to-enable-c17-support-in-vscode-c-extension)

Comment: @SimonKraemer no, my problem refers to a compiler that has a default language version c++14 and I want to change it permanently to version c++17, but thanks for answering

Comment: You could add an alias to your shell if that's what you want. If you are using an IDE you should set the version in the project settings of the IDE (see my first comment).
I am not aware of any possibility to change the default version in any compiler. Usually you configure such things on a project level in make, CMake, your IDE or similar.

Comment: Similar question has been answered here https://superuser.com/q/449441/376011

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default C++ standard in g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648978/change-default-c-standard-in-g)